# Just started getting an HTTP 500 error when connecting to Azure Key Vault from an ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

We have an application built on ASP.NET Core which has been happily running on an Azure App Service for several months now. There is a second, completely separate instance of the application for disaster recovery purposes hosted in a different Azure region.

Both apps connect to a single Key Vault to retrieve various secrets and keys. The App Services use a managed identity with appropriate access controls on the Vault. The following code is used to retrieve secrets:

```
var client = new SecretClient(KeyVaultUri, new DefaultAzureCredential());
return client.GetSecret(name).Value;
```

As I say, this has been working fine for months.

Recently it stopped working, raising the following error message for 100% of requests to BOTH apps on the same day:

```
Service request failed.
Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Content:
{"error":{"code":"ServerError","message":"ActivityId: *****, ActivityName: ResolveVault"}}

Azure.RequestFailedException:
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequest (Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequest (Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.SecretClient.GetSecret (Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
```

This lasted several days until I restarted the App Service and it started working normally again. The DR instance has not been restarted and still doesn't work.

I can't find any information on this particular error, and it seems very strange that it affected both applications at the same time. Can anybody offer any insight on the cause?

Comment: Azure has [had some issues lately](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status/history/). You haven't mentioned exactly when this happened, but it could be related to an outage. We had to recycle some apps after the Azure AD outage to get them running again.

Comment: @Crowcoder oh! First thing I did was check the current status in Azure as the issue was ongoing but it looked ok. I didn't check the status history. The first incident on your link covers the exact timeframe in which this started, in the same regions too! Thanks for pointing that out, I guess this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls allow me to sum up here. As @Crowcoder said above, we can see [azure reported issue here](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status/history/), and exactly Op's problems come from outage.

When meeting weird problems from azure services which served on stable running programs, we could take a look at the Azure status history website.